# Kubernetes unable to create impersonator account timeout

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Hosting: Azure centos VM's running RKE1

```
Rancher Version: v2.6.2

Kubernetes Version: 1.18.6
```

Looking for help diagnosing this issue; I get two error messages

1. From Rancher:

   ```
    Cluster health check failed: Failed to communicate with API server during namespace check: Get "https://<NODE_IP>:6443/api/v1/namespace/kube-system?timeout=45s": write tcp 172.16.0.2:443 -> <NODE_IP>:7832:i/o timeout
   ```
2. From Kubectl:

   ```
    unable to create impersonator account: error setting up impersonation for user user-sd7q9: Put "https://<NODE_IP>:6443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/cattle-impersonation-user-sd7q9": write tcp 172.17.0.2:443-> <NODE_IP>:7832: i/o timeout
   ```

Nothing appears to be broken and my applications are still available via ingress.

https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/34671